# Set algebra and expected value, this manipulation is correct?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Im doing a problem where I must evaluate the expected value of random variable $XY$, where $Y=M-X$.

My question, this manipulation is correct?

$$\Bbb E[XY]=\Bbb E[X\cap Y]=\Bbb E[X\cap (M\cap X^c)]=\Bbb E[\varnothing]=0$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense.  You're treating the variables as if they were sets, but they aren't.  For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, what does $X\cap Y$ mean?  And the result you're getting is not true: for instance, if $M=2X$, then $Y=X$, so $E(XY)=E(X^2)$, which is usually not $0$.

Comment: Yes, it seems a math brutality but I needed to confirm xD